# HighStock with Multiple X-Axes, ToolTip is not showing values of all series

Tags: highcharts

I am using [HighStock](https://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock) for comparative analysis, where it shows same number of series during different time periods, as shown in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdulQ/K4Cj6/179/) `fiddle`.
It has multiple x and y axes. when I move mouse over the chart, it shows series wit value at mouse current location.
Problem:
Problem in this chart is, tooltip do not show values of all series, but a few and those series change in tooltip window. I want tooltip to show all series with corresponding or nearest point value at mouse location.

Another problem is with navigator, navigator is showing only dates corresponding to first x-axis it should show dates of all axes, stacked one above the other(like in chart), 
Moreover, when I minimize the navigator window, it shorten only first x-axis but not all, I want it to shorten all x-axes. The said issue can be observed in following image.

Comment: Issue with tooltip is a regression from [this issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5832). With Highstock 5.0.0 it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/K4Cj6/181/ Regarding navigator: it's always connected to the first xAxis in a chart. You can create your idea with stacked series on the [UserVoice](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api). To correct extremes, you can use [afterSetExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes). Bug reported [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6697) - thanks!

Comment: @PawełFus, thank you, as you have already filed an issue, but stepping back from 5.0.11 to 5.0.0 is not a good idea,as we will have to compromise some other fixes. This issue is our show blocker, could you please tell me, how long it will take to fix this issue?

Comment: The issue was just reported, so it's hard to say. Once it will be decided it will receive milestone label or, if it's an easy fix, then it will be sooner without any label.